# rmarkdown html page loaded with warning message

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have created simple rmarkdown - flexboard html page, using MASS/painters dataset, preview looks fine, but as soon as view in browser, the html page loads with warning, with below below errors.

Please note I have used rpivottable and DT to present painters data. Any guidance would be helpful.

> ---
>
> ````
> title: "Untitled"
> output:
>  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
>    orientation: columns
>    vertical_layout: fill
> --- 
> ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
> library(flexdashboard)
> ````
>
> ```
>      Column {data-width=650}
>
> ---

````
### Chart A
```{r}
```
Column {data-width=350}
````

---

````
  ### Chart B
  ```{r}
  ```
  ### Chart C
  ```{r}
  ```
````

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/15.0.874.121; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>       Timestamp: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 10:58:22 UTC
>
> Message: '$' is undefined Line: 833 Char: 5 Code: 0
>
> Message: Object expected Line: 2562 Char: 1 Code: 0
>
> Message: Object expected Line: 2599 Char: 1 Code: 0

Comment: Could you please make this into a reproducible example? Otherwise we can only tell you what the error message says; we have no way to fix it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added code snippet. Any help would be really appreciated.